# Sorting df rows horizontally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': {0: u'1:19374802:19380807',
                              1: u'2:4608900:4614600',
                              2: u'5:14175176:14182011',
                              3: u'2:4608900:4614600',
                              4: u'5:14171600:14173742'},
                   'target': {0: u'2:4608900:4614600',
                              1: u'5:14175176:14182011',
                              2: u'2:4608900:4614600',
                              3: u'5:14171600:14173742',
                              4: u'2:4608900:4614600'}})

    source              target
0   1:19374802:19380807 2:4608900:4614600
1   2:4608900:4614600   5:14175176:14182011
2   5:14175176:14182011 2:4608900:4614600
3   2:4608900:4614600   5:14171600:14173742
4   5:14171600:14173742 2:4608900:4614600
```

The data is originating from multiple iterations over many to many relationships. In the data, `Source:Target == Target:Source`. Thus relationships get duplicated (rows 1 and 2 for example).

I'm looking to sort the rows horizontally:

```
    source              target
0   1:19374802:19380807 2:4608900:4614600
1   2:4608900:4614600   5:14175176:14182011
2   2:4608900:4614600   5:14175176:14182011
3   2:4608900:4614600   5:14171600:14173742
4   2:4608900:4614600   5:14171600:14173742
```

So duplicates can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd do it using NumPy, as it might be faster:

```
In [40]: pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=df.columns).drop_duplicates()
Out[40]:
                source               target
0  1:19374802:19380807    2:4608900:4614600
1    2:4608900:4614600  5:14175176:14182011
3    2:4608900:4614600  5:14171600:14173742
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
df.apply(sorted, axis=1)
```