# Efficient way in Pandas for removing columns with duplicate values in different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am looking for a an efficient and elegant way in Pandas to remove "duplicate" rows in a DataFrame that have exactly the same value set but in different columns.

I am ideally looking for a vectorized way to do this as I can already identify very inefficient ways using the Pandas `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()` method.

Say my DataFrame is:

```
source|target|
----------------
| 1   |  2   |
| 2   |  1   |
| 4   |  3   |
| 2   |  7   |
| 3   |  4   |
```

I want it to become:

```
source|target|
----------------
| 1   |  2   |
| 4   |  3   |
| 2   |  7   |
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, many questions ask about this. Take look maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603520/pandas-remove-duplicates-that-exist-in-any-order

Comment: This is a duplicate indeed. The link RafaelC  provided lies your answer. Your solution is here: `pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=df.columns).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Many thanks, sorry for not spotting this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting df rows horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884131/sorting-df-rows-horizontally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,axis=1)).duplicated()]

    source  target
0   1   2
2   4   3
3   2   7
```

**explanation**:

`np.sort(df.values,axis=1)` is sorting DataFrame column wise

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

then making a dataframe  from it and checking  `non duplicated` using prefix `~` on `duplicated`

`~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,axis=1)).duplicated()`

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

and using this as `mask` getting final output

```
    source  target
0   1   2
2   4   3
3   2   7
```

Comment: Hi Akhilesh, while this may be the correct answer, you should be leaving a little insight/ explanation of what you have done here to make it a quality answer which will help others understand the root cause of problem.

Comment: @nircraft thank you for pointing it out. please check updates