# drop duplicates on multiple columns irrespective of the order (a/b == b/a)

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Is there any way to delete rows of duplicated pairs in pandas without taking the order into account?

Dataframe before deleting  --> want to delete duplicate pair (yellow colored)

[image]

After deleting duplication

[image]

example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,1,1,2,2],
                   'b': [2,1,3,4,3,4]
                  })
```

Comment: `df.groupby(df.apply(frozenset, axis=1)).first()`

Comment: You're welcome. I thought this was a duplicate but I can't find one, so I provided an answer

Comment: @mozway - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480504/efficient-way-in-pandas-for-removing-columns-with-duplicate-values-in-different

Comment: thanks @jezrael given the low activity and non ideal answer of the dup, not sure if I should close here and post there or leave it as it is

Comment: @mozway - yoour solution is good if small data, if large better is dupe.

Comment: I would say the other way around, sorting is more expensive than creating a set

Comment: @mozway - ya, depends of data, - one year ago - if remember well jpp do some tests for `frozenset`s vs `numpy.sort`.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) to have a common, unordered item to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), then take the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) item per group:

```
df.groupby(df.apply(frozenset, axis=1), as_index=False).first()
```

or use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) on the `frozenset` Series:

```
df[~df.apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
```

output:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4
3  2  3
4  2  4
```

Comment: `df[~df.apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]`?